# Caption style lost due to subcaption or subfig packages loading

Tags: captions, subcaption, subfig

I'm asking if there are any way to use the `subcaption`package, without load its own style. 
To be more precise I have a LaTeX template with the relative `.sty` file that gives me this type of caption style:

[image]

If I try to load the `subcaption` or `subfig` packages, I totally lost this style.

There is any way to use these packages maintaining the original template style or to enumerate figures with letters like `subfig` does without these packages?
I'm using the IOP latex template available here: [Iop Template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/institute-of-physics-(iop)).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you checked how the local .sty-file does this formatting. Perhaps it's already loading a package which enables you to use their definition in your usecase.

Comment: Yeah I have checked, but for me not so obvious to find. There are a lot of command that begins with "caption" or "tablecaption"

Comment: What happens if you load `subcaption` or `subfig` prior to your custom sty?

Comment: @Skillmon, Happens the same thing, all caption style change. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use something like `subfig` the following gives at least some close behaviour, though it does need a bit more manual work. I hope this works together with your template (I refrain from visiting third party sites upon answering questions on TeX.SX, therefore didn't test with your template)!

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % to hook into `figure` and reset the mysubfig counter

% reset the counter (it is unlikely that another figure environment has
% additional subfigures of the previous one
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{mysubfig}{0}}


\newcounter{mysubfig}[figure]% also reset after the figure-counter has increased
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mysubfig{\@ifstar\mysubfig@above\mysubfig@below}
\newcommand*\mysubfig@above{%
  \renewcommand*\themysubfig{\thefigure(\alph{mysubfig})}%
  \refstepcounter{mysubfig}(\alph{mysubfig})}
\newcommand*\mysubfig@below{%
  \renewcommand*\themysubfig{\the\numexpr\c@figure+1\relax(\alph{mysubfig})}%
  \refstepcounter{mysubfig}(\alph{mysubfig})}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
You could place the figures into \texttt{minipage}s with individual
\verb|\caption|s:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{left picture}
    \label{fig:1l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{right picture}
    \label{fig:1r}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Or you put some letters semi-manually beneath them. If the caption is below the
figures use the unstarred version:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:2l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:2r}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{In \ref{fig:2l} we see an A; in \ref{fig:2r} we see a B}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

Else use the starred version:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{In \ref{fig:3l} we see an A; in \ref{fig:3r} we see a B}
  \label{fig:3}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \mysubfig*\label{fig:3l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \mysubfig*\label{fig:3r}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Just to see if it works if you use the unstarred after the starred version.
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:4l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:4r}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{In \ref{fig:4l} we see an A; in \ref{fig:4r} we see a B}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the first page of the output (cropped to interesting parts):
[image]

**Note:**

The formatting of the figure counter in the labels to the `\mysubfig`s have to be adapted to match the formatting of `\thefigure`. The below code doesn't need that, but I don't guarantee it to be compatible with packages that change `\refstepcounter` (though I did a short test with `hyperref` and it seemed to work out).

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % to hook into `figure` and reset the mysubfig counter

% reset the counter (it is unlikely that another figure environment has
% additional subfigures of the previous one)
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setcounter{mysubfig}{0}}


\newcounter{mysubfig}[figure]% also reset after the figure-counter has increased
\renewcommand*\themysubfig{\thefigure(\alph{mysubfig})}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mysubfig{\@ifstar\mysubfig@above\mysubfig@below}
\newcommand*\mysubfig@above{%
  \refstepcounter{mysubfig}(\alph{mysubfig})}
\newcommand*\mysubfig@below{%
  \bgroup
  \advance\c@figure by 1
  \xdef\mysubfig@thefigure{\thefigure}%
  \egroup
  \stepcounter{mysubfig}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
    \p@mysubfig\mysubfig@thefigure(\alph{mysubfig})}%
  (\alph{mysubfig})%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
You could place the figures into \texttt{minipage}s with individual
\verb|\caption|s:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{left picture}
    \label{fig:1l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{right picture}
    \label{fig:1r}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Or you put some letters semi-manually beneath them. If the caption is below the
figures use the unstarred version:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:2l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:2r}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{In \ref{fig:2l} we see an A; in \ref{fig:2r} we see a B}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

Else use the starred version:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{In \ref{fig:3l} we see an A; in \ref{fig:3r} we see a B}
  \label{fig:3}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \mysubfig*\label{fig:3l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \mysubfig*\label{fig:3r}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Just to see if it works if you use the unstarred after the starred version.
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:4l}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \mysubfig\label{fig:4r}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{In \ref{fig:4l} we see an A; in \ref{fig:4r} we see a B}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! It works. The last code you put, works aligning perfectly the image, instead the first one doesn't. You saved me!!!

Comment: @SimonG that's funny, because the output is exactly the same for me. But if it does work, I'm glad I could help.